# Points to volume setup optimization?

Tags: geometry-nodes, optimization

in order to greatly optimize my geometry node setup, i need to find a way to remove the two nodes circles in blue (let's call it the blue group) on the pictures.

These nodes are responsible for the generation of my shapes, but creates a lot of computing time. The 3D shape is then smoothed with a repeat zone setup and flattened on XY plane.
Lastly i'm deleting everything inside to extract the outline curves.

I need to instance at least 200 of those shapes and my computer starts lagging at around ~20 instances. My guess is that the "Blue Group" is the limit since it generates around 1.5k vertices.

[image: the whole setup with the Blue Group mentionned]
[image: outliner]

Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is look like that using volumes is overkill for your setup, since you only care about flat outline.

So maybe try to set this like this:

[image]

This setup extract shapes from a flat plane, avoiding voxels

Comment: Well I used a better computer and computed a few hundreds shapes with my setup under 5 seconds, so i'll stick to it. But your method will allow me to generate details which is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To "Debug" your Node Graph I suggest to turn on "Timings" in the Geometry Node Editor.  [image]

As an alternative to your current approach you can use the [Convex Hull Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/operations/convex_hull.html)

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvoted, the use of convex hull is very nice. I'll use it for this project ! Thank you !